# How can I install package in pip such that older packages will not break?

Tags: python, pip

I have a project where I am trying to limit how much I update packages (for stability). For example, I have an older version of `scipy`. This is specified in my requirements.txt file with a strict `==a.b.c` version.

Since `scipy` at the specified version depends on certain (older) versions of some packages (e.g. `libgcc`), it broke when I installed some other packages that required newer versions of `libgcc` (specifically [`stripy`](https://pypi.org/project/stripy/)). I fixed my environment by uninstalling `stripy` and `scipy`, then reinstalling `scipy` only. I assume what happened was that pip tried to get the newest version of `stripy`, while `scipy` was locked in place.

The issue is, I still want to use `stripy`. Along with other packages, that might need newer dependencies for their newest available version. How can I tell pip that I don't need the newest version available, I just need one that's compatible with what I have in my current environment?

Comment: pip is not too good at doing this sort of thing ad-hoc. Recommend to use an environment manager which puts a bit more effort into the dependency solving like conda or poetry.

Comment: Poetry still uses the same packaging metadata as pip. As far as I know conda has access (in some cases) to better/fresher packaging metadata, so it might be a bit better for this use case. But I do not know how much better it would really be. -- In principle _pip_ does dependency resolution more or less as good as any other installer, it is the packaging metadata that is usually not good enough for these kind of situations. Especially when it is about older things, packaging metadata is rarely kept up to date, new incompatibilities are rarely added back to older existing releases.